# How to resolve @import with Webpack3

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-css

I'm trying to add [semantic-ui-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semantic-ui-css) to my `React` application. But, I'm receiving this error message:

> "Invalid or unexpected token".

The traceback indicates an issue parsing the `@import`. Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Also, I realize many other people have had this problem, but haven't found a solution on Stack that works yet. Full source is available here: https://github.com/lgants/django-react-ssr.

**frontend/webpack.client.base.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');
var CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/client/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: '[name]-[hash].js',
    publicPath: '/static/js/',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../backend/app/static/js/')
  },
  // tells webpack to run babel on every file it runs through
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          presets: [
            'react',
            'stage-0',
            ['env', { targets: { browsers: ['last 2 versions'] } }]
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|gif)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=1024&name=[name]-[hash:8].[ext]!image-webpack-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.jpg$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      },
      {
       test: /\.css$/,
       use: [
         'style-loader',
         'css-loader'
       ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ use: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader' })
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'less-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff2?)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new BundleTracker(
      {
        filename: './webpack-stats.client.json'
      }
    ),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin([
      'backend/app/static/js/main-*.*', 'backend/app/static/js/*.hot-update.*'
    ],
      {
        dry: false,
        root: path.resolve(__dirname, '..'),
        watch: true
      }
    )
  ]
};
```

**frontend/webpack.client.dev.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');
var merge = require('webpack-merge');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var baseConfig = require('./webpack.client.base.config.js');
var CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const config = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  ]
};

module.exports = merge(baseConfig, config);
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Where is the error coming from? Which part is failing? Have you included the code that you think is at fault? What have you tried?

Comment: Which file are you using the `@import` in? Is it inside a .scss file?

Comment: The import is a google font and it’s in a css file provided by semantic-ui-css.